# Jquery load clicked link if confirmed from dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this jquery code:

```
    $("#deletec-box").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    resizable:false,
    height:230,
    modal:true,
    buttons:{
        "Confirm":function(){
            window.location=$("a[id*='deletec-confirm']").attr('href');
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },Cancel:function(){
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("a[id*='deletec-confirm']").click(function(){
    $("#deletec-box").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

And in the web page I have:

```
<a href="?action=delc&cid=2" id="deletec-confirm2" title="Delete This Record">Delete</a>
<a href="?action=delc&cid=3" id="deletec-confirm3" title="Delete This Record">Delete</a>
```

When you click the second link above it uses the first links url to load. How can I get the jquery dialog box to get the correct url based on the link clicked above? All I want to do is if they click the delete link it asked to confirm, if they click the confirm button in the dialog box I want the url they originally click to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

1. Use the [jQuery data API](http://api.jquery.com/data/)
   The idea here is to store the appropriate information at a known location and use that within your dialog. For example:

   ```
   $("#deletec-box").dialog({
       autoOpen:false,
       resizable:false,
       height:230,
       modal:true,
       buttons:{
           "Confirm":function(){
               window.location=$('#deletec-box').data('loc');
               $(this).dialog("close");
           },Cancel:function(){
               $(this).dialog("close");
           }
       }
   });

   $("a[id*='deletec-confirm']").click(function(){
       $('#deletec-box').data('loc', $(this).attr('href'));
       $("#deletec-box").dialog("open");
       return false;
   });
   ```
2. Modify the dialog when needed with the appropriate buttons. This might be too verbose though and more work than it's worth plus the overhead of creating a lot of objects.

   ```
   $("#deletec-box").dialog({
       autoOpen:false,
       resizable:false,
       height:230,
       modal:true,
   });

   $("a[id*='deletec-confirm']").click(function(){
       loc = $(this).attr('href');
       $('#deletec-box').dialog({
           buttons:{
                   "Confirm":function(){
                       window.location=loc;
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   },Cancel:function(){
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
           }
       });
       $("#deletec-box").dialog("open");
       return false;
   });
   ```